# Animation node instancing an object with children

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to instancing an object with all it's mesh children, but i can't find a way, I've seen in previous version of blender the "object from groups" but now that there is the collection system, i can't.
Any good solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to instantiate every object in the collection at once, or do you have a specific object in a collection, and you want to instantiate this object and all their children ? Do you want to instantiate every mesh inside one single object or do you want to instantiate as many objects as there are children + the parent ?

Comment: Thank you for your supportoI have different mesh children of a null parent animated in locscrot, now I'd like to instantiate many of this animated Object and offset animation of the null parent also.

Comment: I'vr tried different way but seems there is no way unless join all object in one object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an object doesn't store reference to its children, I would advise to use a collection for this, and create an empty as a collection instancer. Be aware that every instanced collection will have the same animation as the first one:

For example, I have this collection with a cube and a Suzanne children.

[image]

Create empties as instance collections :

[image]

Loop over them and change their position :

[image]

Increase the number of instances :

[image]

Comment: Thank you 1000 times for your support!!

Comment: @Gorgious is it possible to access the position of a collection instances's child? in your case let's say the world position of each individual suzanne?